# Same code works for some IDEs but not others

Tags: python, anaconda

I am very confused about the following problem. I simply do not understand how my computer works.

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data as wd 
import quandl 

tickers = ['MSFT','AAPL','F','GE'] 
new_data_01 = pd.DataFrame() 
for ii in tickers:
    new_data_01[ii] = wd.DataReader(ii, data_source = 'yahoo', start ='2001-1-1')['Adj Close']
new_data_01.head()
```

This works perfectly well when I run it both in Spyder and Anaconda notebook. However not when I run it in IDLE. I don't understand why. This is the error I get when I run the code in the IDLE...

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andres/Desktop/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    new_data_01[ii] = wd.DataReader(ii, data_source = 'yahoo', start ='2001-1-1')['Adj Close']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 291, in DataReader
    raise ImmediateDeprecationError(DEP_ERROR_MSG.format('Yahoo Daily'))
pandas_datareader.exceptions.ImmediateDeprecationError: 
Yahoo Daily has been immediately deprecated due to large breaks in the API without the
introduction of a stable replacement. Pull Requests to re-enable these data
connectors are welcome.

See https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues
```

Comment: Are you sure that all of them are using the same version of Python/pandas?

Comment: You should change your title to describe the actual issue or question.

Comment: Might check https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/507

Comment: For the IDLE:
print(sys.version)
3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 03:03:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
For Spyder:
3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 26 2018, 08:42:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please provide the versions of Pandas Datareader in both IDEs?

```
import pandas_datareader as pd

print(pd.__version__)
```

They are likely different, which would explain your error. Yahoo Finance was [deprecated](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/pull/450) in Pandas Datareader version 6.0. Parts of the API were recently reinstated and are supported in the latest development version (the master branch of the [Github repository](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader)).

If one IDE has a version other than 6.0, your request would not be met with an `ImmediateDeprecationError` in that environment. I would recommend downloading the latest version of Pandas Datareader from the Github repo on both IDEs.